# Why does my app crash when my server is not connected?

Tags: android, exception, try-catch, http-post, http-get

I send some parameters to my server with httpGet or httpPost and it works fine when my client is connected to my server. But when it's not, my app crash. However, I have a try/catch...

Look at my code:

```
 ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pickSurnom)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {


                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Postit.this);

                            alert.setTitle("Modifier votre surnom");
                            //alert.setMessage("Message");

                            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                            final EditText input = new EditText(Postit.this);
                            alert.setView(input);

                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                    String surnom = input.getText().toString();                                     


                            //Recuperation "id" du user dans les préférences partagées
                                    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    String id = prefs.getString("id", null);



                            //------------------------ENVOI----------------------------

                            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

                                    try {
                                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

                                    //httpGet.setURI(new URI("http://192.168.0.1:8888/user/public"+"?"+"surnom="+((TextView) findViewById(R.id.surnom)).getText().toString()));
                                    httpGet.setURI(new URI("http://192.168.0.1:8888/user"+"?"+"id="+id+"surnom="+ surnom ));

                                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                                                    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

                                                    String ligneLue = bufferedReader.readLine();

                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id="+bufferedReader.readLine() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                    while (ligneLue!=null){
                                                            stringBuffer.append(ligneLue);
                                                            ligneLue = bufferedReader.readLine(); 

                                                            //Si la réponse = True
                                                            //Remplir le bon surnom dans le TextView
                                                            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.surnom)).setText(surnom);

                    }


                            } catch (Exception e){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.e("Exception1", e.getMessage());

                            } finally {
                                    if (bufferedReader !=null){
                                            try{
                                                    bufferedReader.close();
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serveur indisponible" + surnom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            } catch (IOException e){
                                                    Log.e("Exception2", e.getMessage());
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                            Log.i("Exception3", stringBuffer.toString());
```

My LogCat

```
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58): ANR in com.branchu1 (com.branchu1/.Postit)
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58): Load: 0.5 / 0.18 / 0.08
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58): CPU usage from 32503ms to 56ms ago:
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   system_server: 19% = 15% user + 3% kernel / faults: 2075 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.launcher: 3% = 2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1554 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 124 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 56 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 43 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 135 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 27 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 24 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.email: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):  +com.branchu1: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58):  -com.branchu1: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
01-17 15:45:00.801: ERROR/ActivityManager(58): TOTAL: 33% = 25% user + 8% kernel + 0% softirq
```

Comment: Have you looked at your `logcat` to see what line it's crashing at?

Comment: We need more information. Could you give us more precisions about the error, a stacktrace maybe ?

Comment: I edited the post with the logCag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an "Application Not Responding" (ANR) error. This is because you are doing network IO on the main thread, which is always a no-no. If there's no network connection, it will block until it times out.

Always use an AsyncTask for downloading.

Comment: Do you have any example how can i use AsyncTask because I'm confused with the parameters: protected String doInBackground(String... params)

Comment: See example on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Remember the most important features... doInBackground() runs on a seperate thread and must not update the UI because only the main thread can do that. What you return from doInBackground() (ie the results of your download) will be passed to onPostExecute(), which does run on the UI thread, and from which you can safely update the UI.

Comment: NB: Both the return and parameter types to doInBackground are templated because you might want your background function to use and return ints, or Foos, or MyDownloadDataType[] or whatever types are best suited to the work that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I post my code. My app doesn't crash but I want to pass a parameter contained in my layout, and I can't access it in the AsynRask thread. How can I do?

Comment: I fix it by declaring my parameter like this:
new UpdateValeur().execute(surnom); et I can access to it with param[0]...is that good way?

Comment: So long as "surnom" isn't a UI type that you will try and access from the background thread, it's fine. You *never* need to access UI elements from background threads... that's why you have a background thread in the first place, to do non-UI work (i.e. downloading files or reading from disk, etc etc). If say, you wanted to read an EditText or something and pass that to your background thread, then you read the contents to a String and pass that to execute().

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this code with my Tornado ServerWeb and it works perfectly.

Comment: Would you therefore consider that your question has been answered? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing an Android Not Responding (ANR) exception because you are issuing your HTTP requests on the UI thread.  You must make sure the UI thread is always responsive to the user.  It's not happening when your server is connected because the response is fast enough, but on a timeout or other issue, you're going to get this every time.

The answer is to use something like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to issue your HTTP requests on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to find out how to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess:  in the try/catch in your finally block, you're only catching `IOException`.  Maybe calling `.close()` on `bufferedReader` throws a different exception?